# iOS - Autolayout, making UIView 2x the height of its container

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, autolayout

I'm making a game menu using UIKit and I'm just getting my feet wet with autolayout.  I would like to have a large UIView that pans around depending on the buttons you touch.

I'm creating my viewController like so in AppDelegate

```
let menuController = MenuController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: menuController)
```

and in my MenuController

```
let view: UIView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Menu", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as UIView
view.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.addSubview(view)
```

here is the setup i have for my UIView using interface builder

[image]

So far so good, but I would like to slide this UIView up the screen if I touch the menu button, but the UIView automatically gives itself the screen's size.  Is there any way to use autolayout to size this to 2x the size of it's parent container?

I know I can explicitly set the height of this UIView, but then that would need to change depending on the device.  Everything should really have the same size ratio more or less.  I could do this programmatically, but then I'm not sure how I'd place those menu options using interface builder.

If this is the wrong approach, can anybody make any suggestions?

Comment: Which view you want to have the 2x size of its superview, is it hidden somewhere, can't see in the picture.

Comment: The main uiview the black one in the pic

Comment: I see the black view's frame is its superview's bounds, which fills the whole screen, do you want to make it double size? which can cover 2 of the screen size?

Comment: Yes double height exactly

Comment: You can control and select the subView and drag it to its superview, select aspect ration, then you'll see a `Equal Height` constraint, change its value to 0.5:1 or 1:0.5 depending on what the first item is.

Comment: Do I need to use a storyboard to do this?

Comment: Yes, possibly, I tested it in storyboard and found no equivalent option in xib.